# Run command "composer install" when activating wordpress plugin

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

I want to run the command : "*composer install --prefer-dist*" in a wordpress plugin in the hook *register_activation_hook* to install the require vendors. But when I trying to activating the plugin the error below is generate. Do you have a way to install the required composers when activate the plugin?

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\XXXXX' not found in /../wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/my-plugin.php:54 Stack trace: #0 /../wordpress/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php(2300): include() #1 /../wordpress/wp-admin/plugins.php(191): plugin_sandbox_scrape('my-plugin/my-...') #2 {main} thrown in /../wordpress/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin/my-plugin.php on line 54

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not how this should work. You should not be stunning shell commands from a plugin. The proper way to do this is to install dependencies *before* bundling for distribution.

Comment: I try to do this, but the dependencies I used have a huge size. I didn't want have a huge zip file like plugin.

Comment: Well you have to. You can’t run composer from the plugin itself.

Comment: I found a  WP Plugin allow me to upload huge and install huge plugin. It's: Upload Larger Plugins (https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/upload-larger-plugins/).